# Setting the solutions of an equation as a variables

Tags: equation-solving, variable-definitions

This is probably a simple question, but i couldn't find a solid answer. 
So i have an equation

```
Solve[{F[x, y] == 0, G[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}]
```

but i want to use the solutions as part of another function. However the solutions are in the form

```
(* {{x -> 0., y -> 4.}, {x -> 1., y -> 1.}, {x -> 1.5, y -> 0.}, {x -> 0., y -> 0.}} *)
```

Can I convert the solution to an array or otherwise store the solutions as a variable?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the $x$ values:

```
x/. {{x -> 0., y -> 4.}, {x -> 1., y -> 1.}, {x -> 1.5, y -> 0.}, {x -> 0., y -> 0.}}

(0., 1., 1.5, 0}
```

and likewise for the $y$ values, which of course can be named, or:

```
mySols = {x, y} /. {{x -> 0., y -> 4.}, {x -> 1., y -> 1.}, {x -> 1.5, y -> 0.}, {x -> 0., y -> 0.}}
```

(*
{{0., 4.}, {1., 1.}, {1.5, 0.}, {0., 0.}} 
*)

Comment: Thanks.
How would I access the points in the mySols variable?

Comment: @hijodelsol14 I sense you're really new to *Mathematica*.  Nevertheless, you get the $n$th data point as `mySols[[n]]`, so the third data point is `mySols[[3]]`.  Have I solved your question?  Care to upvote or accept my answer?  (Just click on the uparrow to the left of my answer.)